# gitlab change hostname to ip/gitlab

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4

I installed Gitlab from source using this manual https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html

Now GitLab  work on adress http://gitlab.example. I want to change hostname to 192.168.1.1/gitlab.

```
I changed in file /home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml
host: gitlab.example to host: 192.168.1.1/gitlab

in file /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
gitlab_url: http://gitlab.example 
to gitlab_url: http://192.168.1.1/gitlab

I use Apache2.4 and configure with this example 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-apache24.conf

I changed ServerName gitlab.example to gitlab or 192.168.1.1/gitlab
```

But it doesn't work.
What i forget? How can I change URL of gitlab.
Can I use gitlab.example and 192.168.1.1/gitlab at the same time?
Thank for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The servername cannot contain a `/`, so `192.168.1.1/gitlab` will not work.
You could try simply `192.168.1.1`

But if you do not know how to configure apache, you might want to try the ombnibus installation instead...

Comment: Marcolz, thanks for your answer. But this way is not for me. I want to use my existing DB server MariaDB and don't want to install PostgreSQL together with omnibus. I want to install redmine and gitlab on one server. 
I know Apache a little and I try to learn more. I understand that this way (to use Ip/gitlab) is not correct. I think I must use something like "gitlab.example.local" and "redmine.example.local".

Comment: You could (maybe) use a reverse proxy for accessing your GitLab instance via host/path.